How to create oracle db environment in c++ with occi lib?
How to connect with oracle occi C++ library to a docker container - at least creating the environment?
I can connect with a user I created in an oracle 23 free db in a docker container with
sqlplus dbusername/password@localhost:1521/freepdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 23.0.0.0.0 - for Oracle Cloud and Engineered Systems on Mon Dec 9 09:25:08 2024
Version 23.6.0.24.10

Copyright (c) 1982, 2024, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon Dec 09 2024 09:14:52 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 23ai Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.5.0.24.07

SQL> SELECT version FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
 WHERE product LIK  2  E 'Oracle Database%';

VERSION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23.0.0.0.0

The docker container was created such that
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                   PORTS
                   NAMES
629de2771f43   container-registry.oracle.com/database/free:latest   "/bin/bash -c $ORACL…"   5 days ago   Up 8 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, :::1521->1521/tcp   oradb

No environment
However, this example cannot create the oracle db environment:
$ cat dbconnection.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Environment *env = nullptr;

    env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);

    // This was wrong before if(!env)
    if(env)
            cout << "Environment created." << endl;
    else
            cerr << "Environment not created." << endl;
    return 0;
}

Build:
$ g++ -o mwe dbconnection.cpp -I/path/to/oracle/instantclient_23_6/sdk/include   -L/path/to/oracle/instantclient_23_6  -locci -lclntsh

Run the built file:
$ ./mwe
Environment not created.

Runtime exception (surely trying to access null)
Building and executing the following code, gives
Environment not created.

C:\Users\sbollmann\source\repos\oracledbplayground\x64\Release\oracledb.exe (process 21320) exited with code -529697949 (0xe06d7363).

Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string user = "dbusername";
    string password = "password";
    string connectString = "localhost:1521/freepdb1";

    Environment* env = nullptr;
    Connection* conn = nullptr;

    env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
    // This was wrong before if (!env)
    if(env)
        cout << "Environment created." << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Environment not created." << endl;

    conn = env->createConnection(user, password, connectString);
    if (!conn)
        cout << "Connection established." << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Connection not established." << endl;
    return 0;
}


Your code isn't obviously using user, password, or connectString anywhere.  Are you missing some setup code (maybe a structure parameter to the createEnvironment() call)?

@DavidMaze , yes. I upated the question. The mwe is now more minimal. The environment does not need user, password, and db name.. However, later I need the environment to connect to the db.
